# WPF Binded list is updated from datagrid but I don't want it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm new in WPF/C# and I'm in trouble with bindings :(

I've got a ListView in my main Window which is binded from a list.
I've got a second window with a datagrid which is binded from another list (a copy from the first one).

My probleme is when I update datas from the datagrid (2nd window), it upgrades datas from the first window too but I don't want it. (I want the first list to be independant from the other)

Here is the code from the 1st window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Voiture> mesBagnoles = new List<Voiture>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        lstViewBagnoles.ItemsSource = mesBagnoles;
        ...
    }
}
```

xaml :

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lstViewBagnoles" selectionChanged="lstViewBagnoles_SelectionChanged" Width="220">
    <ListView.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
         </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Marque}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Modele}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Moteur}"/>
       </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Openning 2nd window:

```
    private void btnVoitures_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VoituresWindow voitureWindow = new VoituresWindow(mesBagnoles);
        voitureWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

2nd Window :

```
public partial class VoituresWindow : Window
{

    public List<Voiture> listBagnoles = new List<Voiture>();
    
    public VoituresWindow(List<Voiture> e)
    {
        listBagnoles = e;
        InitializeComponent();
        dataVoitures.ItemsSource = listBagnoles;
    }
}
```

And xaml :

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataVoitures" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marque" Binding="{Binding Marque}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modèle" Binding="{Binding Modele}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Moteur" Binding="{Binding Moteur}" />
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, the binding source of the listview and the datagrid are from 2 differents lists.
I think I miss something with DataContext or else but I cannot find a way
Hope you can help me :)

## EDIT :

Ok so I replaced the 2nd window opening :

```
private void btnVoitures_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VoituresWindow voitureWindow = new VoituresWindow(mesBagnoles);
    voitureWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

By this:

```
    private void btnVoitures_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Voiture> mesBagnoles2 = new List<Voiture>(mesBagnoles);
        VoituresWindow voitureWindow = new VoituresWindow(mesBagnoles2);
        voitureWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But the fist window listview is always updated by the 2nd window datagrid :/
I think there is something wrong with my binding

Comment: Its the same list, you passed a reference to it into `VoituresWindow` in the constructor

Comment: Yeah you pass the same mesBagnoles into the 2nd window.

Comment: beginner error :) I just create a new list from the first one and it works very well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sa_ddam213 & Mike Schartz say, you pass the same List to the second window, or as i can read you want a copy of this one.

Just initialize another list and affect it with the value of mesBagnoles.